# window.location.href sometimes returns "web"

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript running on a few sites that collects the window.location.href which the script then sends as a query variable to be logged. In the log files I'm storing I occasionally get an entry that says "web" and I've no idea why. Has anyone else encountered it or knows how to replicate it.

```
var vturl = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Are you sure the `"web"` log entries are not caused by a different call to `console.log`? Can you provide any more information (what browser/version, what site causes this, how often it appears, etc.)? Do you see this behavior in multiple browsers? If you're storing the value in a variable before logging, are you sure the value of that variable has not changed before logging?

Comment: I'm getting the "web" href value from the follow user agents

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Interestingly both have the same referrer

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t

Comment: I realised the fault was my own, I failed to encode the data send to the script and the url variable was being trampled on as the google referrer url also contains a query variable of the same name...oops.